# Неверное имя целевого субъекта. Невозможно создать контекст SSPI

Tags: sql-server, settings

Есть проект у которого есть строка подключения:

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD;Initial Catalog=my_bd;Integrated Security=True"
```

Я указал в файле host что бы подключаться к серверу:

```
190.50.20.10    WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD
```

Теперь сервер пингуется по имени `WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD`

Но при подключении программы к серверу нужно еще указать логин и пароль. Типо пользователь: USER, пароль: 1234. В проекте этого не указывается. Я поменял винду, до смены виндовс где-то в настройках на компе было прописано что при подключении к `WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD` использовать такого-то пользователя и такой-то пароль. Где это прописывается?
Сейчас при запуске программы выскакивает ошибка:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Неверное имя целевого субъекта. Невозможно создать контекст SSPI.

Comment: Эммм, а что за сервер у вас?

Comment: Да собственно тут же в ConnectionString и пишется. Вы бы эта... хоть DBMS и технологию доступа указали... ну или сами на connectionstrings.com поковыряйтеся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот где указывается какое имя и пароль использовать для подключения к `WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD`:

Панель управления\Все элементы панели управления\Диспетчер учетных данных => Учетные данные Windows.

Добавляем:

```
Адресс сервера: WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD:1433
Пользователь: USER
Пароль: 1234
```

Адресс сервера обязательно с указанием порта.
Теперь при подключении к серверу `WIN-FRGGBN1T7FD`в строке подключения не нужно указывать логин и пароль.